# Git and media directory commits

Tags: git, version-control, envoyer.io

I've just started using Envoyer with Bitbucket and one problem I have with a live project is the `media` directory to which users of the system upload different media. If I exclude it from the commits, then they will effectively be removed from the live project on deployment - if I keep them - then they will overwrite the existing ones. What is the approach for this sort of situation, where you only want to commit them first time and then ignore on each sub-sequent deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.gitignore`  to the `media` directory:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

Comment: I'm afraid Envoyer will overwrite everything so this won't really solve the problem - the answer appears to be simply symlinking the media directory.